# programmatically printing a Simulink diagram to SVG

Tags: matlab, simulink

I can print a simulink diagram to SVG with this:

```
print -dsvg -sYYYY myfile.svg
```

where YYYY is the name of my simulink diagram, but it rotates the diagram 90 degrees counterclockwise!

Is there a way to do this so it doesn't get rotated?

(alternatively, to programmatically rotate it 90 degrees clockwise, but that seems like a complete pain, as I can't even manage to do that manually.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `orient` command prior to calling `print`:

```
orient('YYYY', 'portrait')
print -dsvg -sYYYY myfile.svg
```

Logically, you would think that specifying landscape as the orientation would do the trick, but the output remains rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. Setting it to portrait seems to work though.